# Getting WiFi Signal Strength in a windows ce device

Tags: c#, .net, unmanaged

I am trying to get the WiFi Signal strength of a windows ce device using .net.
My device does not support windows zero configuration making things a bit trickier. My application is already using summit sdk which i am trying to use to get the signal strength. Now to use the summit sdk object library file i have a dll (C++) referencing the library file(.lib). And this c++ unmanaged dll (summit.dll) i am calling in my .net code using p invoke.

In my summit.h file i have defined as below :

```
#ifdef SUMMIT_EXPORTS
#define SUMMIT_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define SUMMIT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

SUMMIT_API int SignalStrength(void);
```

I have added the below code in my summit.cpp class file :

```
 SUMMIT_API int SignalStrength(void)
{
CF10G_STATUS ss;
SDCERR sdcer;
sdcer=GetCurrentStatus(&ss);
return ss.rssi;
}
```

In above code snippet GetCurrentStatus is function provided by summit declared like below in sdc_sdk.h file

SDCERR GetCurrentStatus(CF10G_STATUS *status);

and in my .net class file i have used pinvoke as below :

```
[DllImport("summit.dll")]
        public static extern int SignalStrength();
```

and storing the signal strength value as below :

```
int result=SignalStrength();
```

But it's not giving me any value. Can anyone help me to understand where i am ging wrong? Is there anything i am missing?

Comment: does windows ce even know what wifi is?

Comment: Are you sure the int shouldn't be marshalled as an IntPtr?

Comment: Yes this device already has wifi functionality developed in it and can connect to available wifi sources.

Comment: @lrb : i have tried this [return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)] but no luck..